# Count words in list of strings Haskell

Tags: haskell

So i have to count every word in a list of strings in Haskell

Example:

Cwords ["one string random", "hello asd", "asd"] -> 6

This is how i tried:

```
Cwords :: [String] -> Int
Cwords = length . map words
```

Now it gives 3 for the same input

Comment: `map f xs` will always be a list with the same length as `xs`, no matter what function `f` is.

Answer (score 4):

**For each element** of the list, you want to find the **length** of the **words**, aka `map (length . words)`. You'll then have an `[Int]` where each element is the length of the words in that element, so you want to **sum** it up:

```hs
cwords :: [String] -> Int
cwords = sum . map (length . words)
```

Note that functions must start with a lowercase letter.